# Convert scientific number format to number in german Excel

Tags: excel, office365

The source CSV contains numbers formatted like `13.558010465075`. I want to import this CSV into german Excel without manual action of replacing point with comma. Without replacing these numbers are after import displayed in scientific notation like `1,3558E+13`.

There are two methods to convert scientific number notations like `1,3558E+13` to number `13.558010465075`:

1. to use `=trim()`
2. to use an option "format cells", like on the screenshot:

[image]

Both options don't work for me, maybe because I'm on german Excel. *Don't work* means: on usage of both methods decimal delimiter is lost, I get `13558010465075` instead of `13.558010465075`.

Does somebody know any workaround for this issue?

Here are some first lines of my CSV data:

```
+----------------------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| URL                  | Top-10 | Top-100 | Anteil Sichtbarkeit |
+----------------------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| https://example.com/ | 232    | 1.259   | 13.558010465075     |
+----------------------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| https://example.com/ | 272    | 1.265   | 7.3158706637119     |
+----------------------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| https://example.com/ | 280    | 1.327   | 6.8266713736524     |
+----------------------+--------+---------+---------------------+

URL;Top-10;Top-100;"Anteil Sichtbarkeit"
https://example.com/;232;1.259;13.558010465075
https://example.com/;272;1.265;7.3158706637119
https://example.com/;280;1.327;6.8266713736524
```

Comment: Why would 13558010465075.0  be equivalent to 13.558010465075 ?

Comment: `1,3558E+13` states that the decimal is 13 places to the right from which it is shown. so the number is `13,558,000,000,000.00` not `13.558`  that would be `1,3558E+1`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson It is not equivalent - but I get it after trimming or cell formatting instead of correct value. This is the issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner the correct value is `13.558010465075`, which is expected after conversion - I see it looking into CSV file with my code editor. And `1,3558E+13` is what I'm getting after importing CSV into Excel.

Comment: Ah, now we are getting to the route of the problem.  You have a csv that uses `.` as the decimal separator and importing it into an excel that has a local setting of `,` as the decimal separator.  That is information we needed to better understand your problem

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, I failed to mention it at the beginning - its because I get this CSV as an export from a third party tool and not created it by myself.

Comment: You will need to replace the `.` with `,` in the csv in a text editor, BEFORE opening in excel.  Or you will need to import that column as Text using the import wizard.  Then use the VALUE() formula on that column, ie: `=VALUE(A1,".")`  You will not be able to open the csv directly into excel.  You could also change your local settings to use `.` as the decimal, but that effects all of windows not just Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner I already do it on this way, like you say. With my question about any workaround I was hoping to avoid manual action.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the needed details: the format in the source csv file and the desired workflow.

Comment: There is none.  Once Excel opens the file it is corrupted and can no longer be reversed.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson did it already.

Comment: You would probably be better served by **IMPORT**ing the file using either the legacy wizard or Power Query.  With the legacy wizard, you can specify the decimal and thousands separator that the CSV file is using; in Power Query, you specify the "locale". Then you can save that query so it can be re-used whenever you need to import an updated CSV.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld import wizard lets decimal divider disappear. Power Query didn't try yet, will do.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you setting the decimal and thousand separator correctly?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes. With point as decimal divider and comma as thousend divider I indeed convert scientific numbers into numbers correctly. But another column's data with usual numbers gets broken - point as thousand divider according to setting turns into comma. If I let setting of thousand divider out, scientific numbers >1, like `13.558010465075`, turn into `13.558.010.465.075`.

Comment: What you write is confusing to me. I think an example of your CSV file (copy/paste of the text) along with a statement as to your Windows Regional Settings (decimal and thousands separator, and country) will be of value in trying to figure out a reliable import method for your data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I edited my post with some first lines from my CSV

Comment: That looks like a copy/paste from an **Excel table** formatted with markup. Need to see what the actual CSV looks like.  Open the CSV in a text editor (like Notepad or Notepad++) and copy/paste from there.

Comment: In any event, I cannot reproduce your problem using the legacy wizard and what I think the actual CSV file will look like.  If I set my Windows Regional Settings to German; store the csv file as you show with a dot for a decimal separator; and set the legacy wizard to consider dot as the decimal separator (and comma as the thousands separator), the values are imported properly and displayed with the German decimal separator (a comma since that is what the WRS are set to).  Same behavior in PQ setting the datatype properly using locale.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it is a copyPaste directly from CSV file. As you can see, the main problem is caused by same delimiter for thousand and decimal in the last two columns. If I get the last column correctly displayed, the third column goes broken.

Comment: Thank you for adding the copy/paste from the CSV file (which is really a semicolon delimited file). And to clarify, are you writing that the last column is using "dot" for the decimal separator, and the penultimate column using "dot" for the thousands separator?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are writing correctly, the problem is that in the penultimate column, the dot represents a thousands delimiter, and in the last column, the dot represents a decimal delimiter.

This is pretty strange in a CSV file and I would double check with the source to get that corrected.

If that cannot be corrected, then Power query can be useful as you can separately format the two columns upon import, but you will have to get into the Advanced Editor to do so.

- Import the file with `GetData=>from Text/CSV=>Transform`
- `Home=>Advanced Editor`
- Replace the automatically generated `#"Changed Type"` line as seen in the M-Code below:

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\decimals.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=4, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"URL", type text}, 
        {"Top-10", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Top-100", type any},  //<==
        {"Anteil Sichtbarkeit", type number}},
        "en-US" //<==
        ),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Top-100", type number}}, "de-DE")
in
    #"Changed Type with Locale"
```

For the first `Change type` we specify US settings (dot=decimal) **and** we specify the penultimate column as `type any`

Then, in a second step, we specify the penultimate column as being of German settings which will recognize the dot=thousands.

If we then close and load, we get the results below (as seen with German regional settings):

[image]